# Releasing memory blocks from objects in static methods inside a non-static class c#

Tags: c#, memory, stack, static-methods

I'm making use of an static method inside a non-static class,each time that static method is called, a new instance of an object is created

```
       public  class BaseMethodsExecuter<T> where T:class
        {
            public static T Execute(BaseMethodsParams input, BaseBusinessEnum businessEnum) 
            {
                T data=null; 
                try
                {
                  data = ExecuteMethod(input, businessEnum);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
    
                }
                return data;
            }
            private static T ExecuteMethod(BaseMethodsParams input, BaseBusinessEnum businessEnum)
            {
              // this is the line that fell me to thinking 
                var TypeMethod = typeof(BaseDataAbstract<T>).Assembly.GetTypes().Single(t => t.BaseType==(typeof(BaseDataAbstract<T>)) && !t.IsAbstract && ((BaseDataAbstract<T>)Activator.CreateInstance(t)).BaseBusinessMethod== businessEnum);
                var BaseMethod=(BaseDataAbstract<T>)Activator.CreateInstance(TypeMethod);
                var data=BaseMethod.GetBaseData(input);
                return data;
            }
        }
```

Following piece of code creates object in static method

```
((BaseDataAbstract<T>)Activator.CreateInstance(t))
```

As far as i know, `Static objects` hold their memory blocks in **`stack`** part of the memory.
Does it means that each time this method is called an extra space for instantiated object is occupied and never would be released anymore?

How objects inside static methods are cleaned from memory?

Comment: There is no static objects in your code, only static methods. All of them is just ordinary class objects (not even structs) and will be allocated on heap. Std machine size word references on them will be on stack, indeed, but will be disposed once you don't need them.

Comment: `As far as i know, Static objects hold their memory blocks in stack part of the memory.` How did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: Whether a method is static or not has no meaningful impact on how objects declared / instantiated inside that function will act. Objects inside static methods will be cleaned just like objects inside non-static methods.

Comment: Think of references to objects like a rope. In your case the rope is called `data` and you return the rope to the caller. The caller is now holding onto the rope and the rope is connected to the object. The same object may have multiple ropes attached to it. Until all ropes are detached, the object will be in memory. If ropes are attached and you dispose the object, the people who have the rope and try to use the object will get an exception. So even though you leave the method, the rope to the object is still needed so the object still exists and need to exist, otherwise why return it.

Comment: What does change is the name of the rope. In this method it is called `data` and when the method leaves, the name `data` will be thrown away so the stack memory is wiped out. The caller may call the `data` with a new name, or not, but that name will exist within that stack and so on.

Answer (score 2):

First:
Reference Object are stored in the heap. All reference pointers to this object are stored in the stack.
When there are no more pointers in the stack, the object are removed from the heap (See garbage collector).

That being said:
A static object is static reference pointer in the heap to an object in the stack, for that reason the object never gets disposed.
In your example `(((BaseDataAbstract<T>)Activator.CreateInstance(t)).BaseBusinessMethod== businessEnum);` creates an instance but the instance is not assigned to static variable.
Same for `var BaseMethod=(BaseDataAbstract<T>)Activator.CreateInstance(TypeMethod);`, they are assigned to a scoped variable inside `ExecuteMethod`.
Once we jump out of the method, these variables (stack) disappear and the reference objects in the heap disappear when the GC disposes them.

Comment: `They will exist in the heap until disposed` @CodingYoshi Disposing will cause them to be removed from the heap? Do you have any citations for that that I can read further about?

Comment: This bolded part is not true or correct: "Once we jump out of the method, these variables (stack) disappear and **the reference objects in the heap disappear.**" They will exist in the heap until disposed (until GC removes them to be pedantic) or app shut down.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Yes, they disappear because of the GC, I didn't repeat this as it was already in the first section of the explanation. I've edited my response to mention it again.